# MySQL Database Error #1064

Tags: html, mysql, sql, database

I was trying to create a users table in MySQL.
I got the error message 1064. Here is the command I entered.

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
Usrid INT unsigned auto_increment PRIMARY KEY not null,
Username varchar(20),
Name varchar(25),
Surname varchar(25),
Email varchar(50),
Password varchar(50),
);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: remove the comma from the end of Password line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the comma after your last column definition:

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
  Usrid INT unsigned auto_increment PRIMARY KEY not null,
  Username varchar(20),
  Name varchar(25),
  Surname varchar(25),
  Email varchar(50),
  Password varchar(50), <-- HERE
);
```

It should be

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
  Usrid INT unsigned auto_increment PRIMARY KEY not null,
  Username varchar(20),
  Name varchar(25),
  Surname varchar(25),
  Email varchar(50),
  Password varchar(50)
);
```

Comment: Still did not work but thanks!

"Error
SQL query:

CREATE TABLE Users(

Usrid INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2"
Thats the full error message.

Comment: Error
SQL query:

CREATE TABLE Users(

Usrid INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2

Comment: Are you using aprogramming language to run this sql? Or are you doing it from the command line/using a tool like phpmyadmin/sqlyog?